# camel case search in WPF AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, wpf, search, autocompletebox

How implement camel case search (search words with capital letters) in WPF AutoCompleteBox. 
Example: consider my items source contains "Phone Number" then if we type "pn" in text box it suggest phone number in drop down.

Comment: Which autocomplete control are you using?

Comment: using AutoCompleteBox in WPF toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `FilterMode` to `custom` and set a `ItemFilter` predicate to something similar to:

```
autoBox.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.Custom;
autoBox.ItemFilter = new AutoCompleteFilterPredicate<object>((searchText, obj) => 
                    (obj as string).Where(x=>Char.IsUpper(x))
                                   .SequenceEqual(searchText.ToUpper()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the item filter property as described here, there is an example at the bottom.

You can implement your logic like they have implemented the function SearchEmployees.

Simply add a check if a string contains an upper case letter of the input return true else return false.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemfilter(v=vs.95).aspx